# BIOS update Dell inspiron 16 with ubuntu

Tags: drivers, dell, inspiron

I have **Dell Inspiron 16 5625**. It came with **Windows 11** installed but I wanted to give a try with **Ubuntu**, so I replaced the OS.

Now I wanted to update its drivers (like BIOS, graphics, etc.). On the Dell support, they are only giving `.exe` which can only run on Windows. Someone suggested me that I need to install Windows to update drivers and then re-install Ubuntu again.

My question is - is it the right way?

What if I install **Windows** on **VMware** in **Ubuntu** and update the drivers using it, would it work?

**PS**: I've little knowledge of how these drivers work and wanted to update the drviers in my **Ubuntu**.

Comment: You don't have BIOS but UEFI, regardless of the manufacturer still using that old name, and neither are drivers. They're firmware. How to update it depends on what's provided by manufacturer and yes, you could and should have updated while using Windows, for convenience, NOT because it's the only way (and you could've kept Windows in dual-boot). Drivers are OS specific and what you may have done in Windows has no impact whatsoever in Ubuntu (and virtual machines have nothing to do with it).

Comment: In summary, your whole question read as a long "I don't know what I'm doing". So, DON'T. UEFI/BIOS updates are only needed if they correct a problem you're having.

Comment: Dell has a whole website for this  https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/nl-nl/000131486/update-the-dell-bios-in-a-linux-or-ubuntu-environment ;)  "What if I install Windows on VMware in Ubuntu and update the drivers using it, would it work?" No. Keyword here is "virtual": you hardware is virtual in a VM.

Comment: Almost all Dell are in fwupdate. I do not see your model 5625, but if very new it may take a bit before it is available. https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist You can try with its instructions. https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd, also in grub menu. Older systems that fwupdate does not support
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Flashing_BIOS_from_Linux

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to update under Ubuntu is the firmare.
Donload the firmware (as EXE for Windows 10) from the Dell support Webside, save the *.EXE on an USB.
Boot into the BIOS/UEFI (call it what you like), disable the EFI security features, then you can update the firmware with the downloaded file from the USB.
Don't forget to enable the EFI security features afterwards.

Comment: I downloaded both `9343_BIOS_Rev_A05.exe` and `Inspiron_Vostro_5425_5625_1.4.0.exe` and tried them one by one. I first disabled secure boot and then choosing boot from usb. Both the times I got some command line option saying `grub`, I don't understand how to proceed from there
@Andreas